# Alamofire request.resume() cause other suspend request resume

Tags: ios, alamofire

Now my project using

```
public func download(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible, destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination) -> Request {
    return Manager.sharedInstance.download(URLRequest, destination: destination)
}
```

to handle download stuff

I also keep refference of `Request` in a dict

when I stop all `Request` and then I `resume()` certain `Request`  in dict

It isn't just `resume()` that one I chosen, also other request in dict will  `resume()` too.

Any Help?

Comment: I guess the problem is you `keep refference of Request in a dict`, could you post the code of how you construct each Request?

Comment: I don't think so. Just keep ref of the requests, to handle user action like pause or other thinks. The point of the issue is that. I suspend all the requests, and the `resume` one. Some other request will also get `resume` too